# Error: "Received NaN for the `children` attribute. If this is expected, cast the value to a string."

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm getting the error in the title when trying to display data from a dictionary array of arrays.
This is only happening for `change5day` array. Other arrays are reproducing their values in my JSX. Below I show how I implement the working examples and then non working.

```
beta: Array(8) //This object works fine!
0: {symbol: "AAL", beta: 1.5533897423778862}
1: {symbol: "AAPL", beta: 1.2504351069178914}
2: {symbol: "AMD", beta: 1.2406108515690375}
3: {symbol: "FB", beta: 1.1853145746084135}
4: {symbol: "LUV", beta: 1.3727521874575148}
5: {symbol: "MSFT", beta: 1.1366312839677446}
6: {symbol: "NVDA", beta: 1.4118377903501154}
7: {symbol: "TSLA", beta: 1.9493936257640456}


change5day: Array(8) //This object is showing NaN's
0: {symbol: "AAL", day5avg: -0.013411567476948827}
1: {symbol: "AAPL", day5avg: 0.08126016260162605}
2: {symbol: "AMD", day5avg: 0.020594401282525654}
3: {symbol: "FB", day5avg: 0.04620638853545822}
4: {symbol: "LUV", day5avg: 0.034584013050571016}
5: {symbol: "MSFT", day5avg: 0.05570455952135345}
6: {symbol: "NVDA", day5avg: 0.0425905479030535}
7: {symbol: "TSLA", day5avg: 0.02307517944843207}
```

Here is my code:

```
<Tooltip title="Average 5-day volatility Vs. SP500">
    <Typography variant="overline" component="span" color="textPrimary">
        {calculateAvgValue(object.beta) < 1 && "... " + ((calculateAvgValue(object.beta) - 1) * 100).toFixed(2) +"%"}
    </Typography>
</Tooltip>  
</Grid>
<Grid item xs={displayExtraData.view} sm={displayExtraData.view} md={12}> 
    <Typography variant="overline" component="span" color="textSecondary">                                          
        Return
    </Typography>
<Tooltip title="Average 5-day Return ">
    <Typography variant="overline" component="span" color="textPrimary">
        {calculateAvgValue(object.change5day) && "%" + 
((calculateAvgValue(object.change5day) -1) * 100).toFixed(2)}
// This code is reproducing the error in title. I cannot get the value from my function to print
    </Typography>
</Tooltip>
```

`calculateAvgValue():`

```
export function calculateAvgValue(series)
{
    let avg = series.reduce((a, b) => a + b.beta, 0);
    return (avg / series.length)
}
```

How can I get the data to display from `change5day`?

Comment: `calculateAvgValue` looks for a property `beta` on each member object in the `series` array. The `change5day` array members do not have a `beta` property, they have a `day5avg` property. When `calculateAvgValue` tries to access `b.beta` on an object without the `beta` property, it gets `undefined`. `0 + undefined` returns `NaN`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `calculateAvgValue` function sums the array elements by the `beta` property. Since the elements in the `object.change5day` array do not have a `beta` property, `b.beta` in the reducer is `undefined` causing `NaN` to be returned (`0 + undefined` -> `NaN`, `NaN + undefined` -> `NaN`).

Update the `calculateAvgValue` function to receive the key to sum the array by.

```
export function calculateAvgValue(array, key = 'beta') {
  const sum = array.reduce((a, b) => a + b[key], 0)
  return sum / array.length
}
```

You can now call the function passing the array and the `day5avg` key.

```
calculateAvgValue(object.change5day, 'day5avg')
```